# subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['which', 'c++']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, torch, ubuntu-20.04

Please help me, having been confused for almost 2 days.

```
File "/data/ywj/Anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 252, in check_compiler_abi_compatibility
if not check_compiler_ok_for_platform(compiler):
File "/data/ywj/Anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 212, in check_compiler_ok_for_platform
which = subprocess.check_output(['which', compiler], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
File "/data/ywj/Anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
**kwargs).stdout
File "/data/ywj/Anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['which', 'c++']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have installed gcc/g++7.3.0 (non-root) in /data/ywj/gcc73/gcc73

I run this program without this error on the server, but when I connect to the server remotely and run the program in Pycharm, I get this error.

Comment: Well, is `/data/ywj/gcc73/gcc73/bin` on `PATH`? That's what `which` uses to find the compiler.

Comment: I have set like this in Run/Debug Configuration:
PATH         /data/ywj/Anaconda3/envs/torch/bin
PATH2       /data/ywj/gcc73/gcc73/bin
the first path is set to help find Ninja, I don't know whether this two path can work same time

Comment: No, `PATH2` is not read by anything. You separate PATH entries on UNIX systems with colons: `PATH` = `/data/ywj/Anaconda3/envs/torch/bin:/data/ywj/gcc73/gcc73/bin`

Comment: It works,thanks!!!
but....another error comes:
gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
please...

Comment: Thanks again！！！the problem is completely solved

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are building or installing some package.

First, try to get your g++'s version by: `g++ --version`.

```
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Then, add a prefix `CXX=g++-9 CC=gcc-9 LD=g++-9` to your building command, e.g.,:

```
CXX=g++-9 CC=gcc-9 LD=g++-9 pip install xxxx
```

Note that `9` means your g++ version.